# Deleting the head of doubly linked list

Tags: doubly-linked-list

Sorry for such a low quality question but I have no idea why the following code doesn't work.

list points the head of the node.

```
void DeleteHeadNode(Node** list, Node * node)
    {
        if ((*list) == node) {
            Node * next = node->nextnode;
            next->prevnode = NULL;
        free(*list);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It freezes when I try to delete the head consecutively

Comment: That's because your variable `list` has an invalid pointer the second  time - try the code in my answer.

Comment: Was your problem fixed?  Did an answer help?  If so, you should mark it as the selected answer, that's how SO works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `Node**` is used as **alias**. If passed the address of a list variable, one may alter it, by altering the `Node*` value.

In this way one set the passed list variable to null or to the second node.

The following is a usage pattern.

```
void DeleteNode(Node** list, int data)
{
    while (*list != NULL && (*list)->data != data) {
        list = &(node->nextnode);
    }
    if (*list != NULL) {
        Node* found = *list;
        *list = found->nextnode;

        if (found->nextnode != NULL) {
            found->nextnode->prevnode = *list;
        }
        free(found);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Node* list;
...
DeleteNode(&list, ...);
```

A previous node (`prevnode`, a double linked list) is not really necessary.

The `while` loop is of interest: there the alias `list` is set from the list head to the address of a nextnode field. Hence a subsequent change of `*list` either changes the passed list variable or some nextnode field.

```
void SortedInsertNode(Node** list, int data)
{
    Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->data = data;
    node->prevnode = NULL;
    node->nextnode = NULL;
    while (*list != NULL && data >= (*list)->data) {
        node->prevnode = *list;
        list = &(node->nextnode);
    }
    node->nextnode = *list;
    *list = node;

    if (node->nextnode != NULL) {
        node->nextnode->prevnode = *list;
    }
}
```

---

Deleting the head:

```
void DeleteHead(Node** list)
{
    if (*list != null) {
        Node* dead = *list;
        *list = (*list)->nextnode;
        (*list)->prevnede = NULL;
        free(dead);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your rewritten `DeleteNode()` function performs a ***completely*** different operation than that of the OP.  You are not answering the question at all.

Comment: @FKEinternet yes I should have written that (I renamed the function though). Deleting a head I'll add

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing "doesn't work" means `list` is no longer valid after your function - which will be true.

You should have

```
void DeleteHeadNode(Node** list, Node* node)
{
    if ((node != NULL) && (*list == node))    // check node being deleted
    {
        Node* next = node->nextnode;
        if (next != NULL)                     // ensure next exists
        {
           next->prevnode = NULL;
           free(*list);
           list = &next;                      // update pointer to head of list
        }
        else                                  // no next, list is now becoming empty
        {
           free(*list);
           list = NULL;                       // update pointer to head of list
        }
    }
}
```